# Using controller context in partial

Tags: yii

If I define a property `$property` in controller, I can use the property in the views like `$this->property`.

Is it possible to do the same in partials?

I'm able to do only it after defining a getter function in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

$this in a partial is still the current controller, so this works just fine. Perhaps you had a typo?